# Replace strings only outside of quotes using RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like:

```
varA*varB%+Length('10%')
```

I want to replace all the "%" characters **not** within single quotes with "/100" to end up with

```
varA*varB/100+Length('10%')
```

Methinks this is a job for a RegEx?

Comment: somehow i doubt this is doable with regex, especially if there can be multiple nested levels of " and '.

Comment: to simplify - anything within nested levels of quotes should NOT be replaced

Comment: @Guillaume can you explain why?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

non regex solution and not that dirty either ;)

```
    string a = "varA*varB%+Length('10%')";
    string[] b = a.Split('\'');
    string c = string.Empty;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string sbs in b)
    {
        c += i%2==0?sbs.Replace("%","/100"):"'" + sbs + "'";//for the every odd value of i "%" is within single quotes
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: hehe, thanks for this, looks like regexes are pretty unpopular :)

Comment: @NikoG., This is much better than mine. One issue - this is replacing all single quotes which is not a requirement. Once that's fixed, I'll delete my answer in favor of yours. Nice job!

Comment: GreyCloud you are welcome... @James yep, I missed that, will edit

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more efficient solution then the accepted answer.

```
        string a = "varA*varB%+Length('10%')";
        string[] parts = a.Split('\'');
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            parts[i] = _parts[i].Replace("%","/100");
        }
        a = string.Join("'", parts);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the one below. You have to use group and back reference in regex. I've tried it in Ultraedit with Perl regex syntax. It worked well.

```
%([^']) --> /100\1
```

This regex means: find a **%** which is not followed by **'**, like **%a** will be matched. Then replace **%** with **/100** and the one character which follows **%**. In this case, it is **a**.

```
string str = "varA*varB%+Length('10%')";
string output=Regex.Replace(str, "%([^'])", @"/100$1");

string str2 = "varA*varB%+Length('10%')+varA*varB%+Length('10%')+bob%";
string output2 = Regex.Replace(str2, "%([^']|$)", @"/100$1");
```

Comment: Regex.Replace(@"a%b'c%e'e",@"%([^'])", "/100"); gives me a/100'c/100'e which is incorrect as it replaces the % in quotes it also swallowed some characters :(

Comment: You missed \1 in "/100\1". You can verify it here http://regexhero.net/tester/ . It is .net regex test tool. I just tried. It worked.

Comment: So in your question you did not mean % just followed by '? It could be like 'aaa%10bbb' or '10%', right?

Comment: ah is see where you went wrong, i will ammend the question.  I just wanted to match the "%" character

Comment: C# use $ for back reference, not \

Comment: getting closer - fails on varA*varB%+Length('10%')+varA*varB%+Length('10%')+bob% - doesnt match last %